# Counting list size resulting from a findall not working in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I obtain a specific list using findall, and then want to count the number of elements in it.

i.e.

```
huntingbreeds(List) :-
   findall(Breedname, breed(Breedname,_,hunting), List).
```

This returns a need list of hunting dogs from my database [beagle, basset].

But now if i try count it using my new predicate:

```
list_length([] , 0 ).
list_length([_|Xs] , L ) :- 
        list_length(Xs,N) , 
        L is N+1 .
```

with my query 
    ?- list_length(huntingbreeds(List), Count).

This just returns false.

I thought I may need to use arg i.e.

```
?- list_length(arg(1,huntingbreeds(List),L), Count).
```

but again it returns false. 
Anyone know how i can get the list size? I know the function list_length works as if i give it:

```
?- list_length([1,2,3], Count).
```

I get 
    Count = 3.

But just don't know how to pass it my list from the find result. I have tried putting the full findall statement in place of the `huntingbreeds(List)` but that still does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You could  try:

```
huntingbreeds(List),list_length(List, Count).
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,  but I have to create that list_length predicate with the 2 arguments: list_length(List, count), but your comment helped as I created it like this: List_And_Count(L,Count) :- huntingbreeds(L),list_length(L, Count).